# What is the antonym of the noun "creatives"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Web designers, graphic designers, painters, sculptors and whittlers are all largely considered creatives.

If web developers, software developers, programmers and engineers are not also considered creatives - and they usually aren't, in the average person's use of the word - what are they? Is there an antonym for "creatives"?

Example sentence:

> Both creatives and *[non-creatives]* need to work together and adapt to one another's needs to achieve our company's goals.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52338/discussion-on-question-by-hashim-what-is-the-antonym-of-the-noun-creatives).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about **technician**?

Dictionary.com:

> [**technician**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/technician?s=t): a
>   person who is trained or skilled in the technicalities of a subject

**Technicians** are typically trained and skilled but not creative. They focus primarily on helping to implement the ideas of others.

**Addendum**: Now that you've added an example sentence, how about **implementer**?

OD:

**implementer**: one who implements

[**implement**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implement): Put (a decision, plan, agreement, etc.) into effect

Your example:

> Both creatives and **implementers** need to work together and adapt to
>   one another's needs to achieve our company's goals.

Comment: It's not very clear from the dictionary definitions... but a technician is a *doer* rather than a *thinker*. "web developers, software developers, programmers and engineers" would all (in my experience) object to being called "technicians". Taking formula 1 as an example: Adrian Newey (car designer) is an engineer and not a technician; the mechanics who change the tyres in a pitstop could conceivably be called technicians.

Comment: @AndyT I agree that some would object to being called technicians. They would consider it pejorative because it conveys a sense of being [workmanlike](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workmanlike), not creative. It could apply not only to certain IT people but also to painters, designers, musicians, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact antonym, but consider ***techie*** — [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/techie)

> (noun) *informal* A person who is skilled in the use of technological devices, such as computers